# Why does an anonymous inner class have such type when I disassemble the class file using javac?

Tags: java, bytecode, javap

When I disassembled the code given below, I noticed that the TestClass's anonymous inner class in constant pool is displayed as 'AnonymousTestApp$1', but shouldn't it be 'TestClass$1'?

The code:

```
public class AnonymousTestApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass tc = new TestClass(){

        };
    }
}
```

Compiled using Oracle JDK 17 and disassembled using 'javap -c -p -v'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: The "name" of that class is effectively irrelevant, since it's an anonymous name, i.e. it's generated and not for the developer to know or care about.

Second: `AnonymousTestApp$1` is used (by this compiler, that's not defined in the standard) to indicate the first anonymous subclass *contained in* the code of `AnonymousTestApp`.

`TestClass$1` would be the name if the anonymous class was defined inside of `TestClass`.

Think about this problem: If multiple classes in the same package created anonymous subclasses of the same base class, how would they coordinat to avoid name clashes? Using the name of the current top-level class as the prefix avoids such a potential clash.

While `$` *can* be apart of a normal Java identifier, it is [explicitly discouraged in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se19/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8):

> The dollar sign should be used only in mechanically generated source code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.

Comment: `the character $ which can't occur in a proper Java language identifier` The user can use `$` as part of the identifier.

Comment: @英語は苦手: you're right, I misremembered this part. I've updated that section.